# Display blank webpage before webpage loads

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I am trying to create theme for one of the website using tampermonkey , So basically I want to remove everything from page and then add my custom HTML to the page.But there is   actual webpage is displayed for few seconds before my theme appears.I want the website to be completely blank until my custom scripts adds some  custom HTML.

I added following code to tampermonkey

```
// @run-at        document-start
```

And I added following code to empty a webpage first

```
document.body.innerHTML = '';
//my remaining custom codes to add few tables and stuffs
```

So I got this error

VM82 userscript.html:2 ERROR: Execution of script 'display none' failed! Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

To fix this I added settimeout of 100 ms and then

```
setTimeout(function(){
document.body.innerHTML = '';
}, 50);
```

But still for blink of a second actual webpage is being shown.

Answer (score 1):

When the script runs at `document-start` there's no guarantee the body exists. Usually the opposite is expected: the document is completely empty and only document.documentElement is defined which is a DOM element for the `<html>` tag.

Simply [stop the current loading progress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/stop) and use document.open + document.write:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          blank out
// @match         *://*/*
// @run-at        document-start
// ==/UserScript==

stop();

document.open('text/html', 'replace');
document.write(`
<html>
  <body>foo</body>
</html>
`);
```

Note that it may not work if the site's CSP is particularly restrictive. In that case you'll have to use an extension that can relax the CSP (or you can write such an extension yourself).

Comment: Hi , your code works , but if i refresh page 5 times , 1 or 2 times I can still see the actual page

Comment: If you see the original page it can only mean the userscript manager didn't actually run the script at the real document-start, which is probably a bug or a limitation of the extension.

Comment: Ok fine, but What if I want to load other javascripts and libraries of that page , its stopping everything , I have some require jquery etc in tampermonkey , that too getting stopped

Comment: Loading of scripts works for me in Chrome+Tampermonkey both inside document.write and via an explicit appendChild.